# urlbst.sty missing

Tags: urlbst

I want to use package `urlbst` to be able to use `@webpage` in my bibliography. I have installed the using `MiKTeX`. The issue is that `TexWorks` gives me an error saying that `urlbst.sty` is missing. I have both installed the package as user and as admin but the error stays. I have looked on the internet repositories where I can find `urlbst v 0.7` and there is in no archive a `.sty` file. This makes me think that there maybe an error and the package could be incomplete. Could that be? How could I get an appropriate `.sty` file? A Google search does not find it.

Comment: Have you tried `texdoc urlbst`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much more easy to use `biblatex` as other modern users do?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to read the urlbst.pdf, form which you can learn that urlbst is a perl-script used in connection with other *.bst-files. You'll find it at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/urlbst/urlbst.pdf

Comment: Welcome, can you extend the answer a little bit?